# Is the Lambert W function multivalued everywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, lambert-w

Is the Lambert W function multivalued everywhere except at $x=0$?

It is obvious that $W(0)=0\implies 0=0e^0$ because $e^u\ne0$, therefore, it is the coefficient that determines such, and the only coefficient that will work is $0$.

But are *all other* $x$ values going to produce a multivalued function?

Comment: Have you heard of Picard's (little) theorem?

Comment: If we are talking exclusively of reals, $W(x)$ is multivaluated only on $-\frac{1}{e}<x<0$. One value on $x>0$ and no value in $x<-\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'll look that up

Comment: @DanielFischer Picard's theorem can be used to show W is surjective. Does it guarantee, in some simple way, that every nonzero value is taken many times?

Comment: @Wojowu $z \mapsto z\cdot e^z$ is a transcendental entire function. By Picard's theorem, every complex value, with possibly one exception, is attained infinitely often. Since $0$ is attained only once, all nonzero values are attained infinitely often. Although, come to think of it, we need more than just little Picard, but less than big Picard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lambert W-function is multivalued almost everywhere.** We can prove it using Great Picard's Theorem. Consider a holomorphic function $$f(z)=ze^z$$ The function $f$ and $W$ are inverses of each other. Moreover, $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=\tilde{\infty}$. It means that in every neighborhood of infinity (i.e. $|z|>r$) the function $f$ takes on almost all possible complex values *infinitely often*. It implies that its inverse is defined on almost all points, and on every point has *infinitely* many values.

To be specific, $f$ takes value $0$ only once, so $W$ is multivalued for all points except $0$.